# Double backward slash truncating

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting

Consider the following text:

Location: \192.168.22.1\documentation

You'll notice the above only has a single backward slash before the IP address. Here's how the *exact same text* looks when I put it in a code block:

```
Location: \\192.168.22.1\documentation
```

For some reason the first line truncates one of the leading backward slashes while the 2nd does not.

You can see this behavior displayed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924649/file-exists-isnt-find-the-document-but-it-is-there?noredirect=1#comment27941691_18924649). It ended up not being relevant to the guy's problem, but this could easily cause some confusion.

I've checked the [Markdown Editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and don't see this being a result of some formatting rule.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. It is a necessary feature for things like this [Lots of \[\[\[\]\]\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197721/double-forward-slash-truncating) (Source: `[Lots of \[\[\[\]\]\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197721/double-forward-slash-truncating)`)

Comment: those are [backslashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash)

Comment: @nhahtdh I don't really understand what your example is demonstrating

Comment: @tnw: Linking something with lots of `[]` inside. ``\`` is necessary for escaping purpose.

Comment: It’s for escaping. ``\`` is a pretty common escape character, and it’s the one used in Markdown (for example ``\*asterisk’d\*`` will render surrounded by asterisks, not italicized). Code blocks disable Markdown.

Comment: @minitech That makes sense. I guess it's interpreted as escaping the `\` so we only see one. If any of you guys want to add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @tnw: … aaand it also escapes ` in comments. Sort of :D Use two backticks for that one (though I can’t type it here)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It’s for escaping. `\` is a pretty common escape character, and it’s the one used in Markdown (for example, `\*asterisk’d\*` will render surrounded by asterisks, not italicized). Code blocks disable Markdown.

It also escapes itself, as all good escape characters should. Compare:

```
\\example
```

> \example

```
\\\\example
```

> \\example